# Is there a way to refresh eclipse workspace from console before launching eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Possibly asked multiple times; 
Is there a way to refresh eclipse workspace folder from console (linux or windows).

I know there are ant-tasks to do it. but curious to know if there's a command line trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the best you could do is run one of the ant tasks through eclipse.

```
eclipse/eclipse -noSplash \
-application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner \
-buildfile refreshWorkspace.xml \
-data /path/to/workspace
```

Comment: i am not able to find refreshWorkspace.xml ?? where is it.

Comment: You have to write it yourself, using the ant tasks you mentioned you had found.  For reference: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fant_eclipse_tasks.htm